# Angular Display lists from Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

My data in Firebase looks like this...

```
evalu8er
    situations
        -K6rM12D-0nt4fJH_QcA
            situation: "Test"
        -K6rPoHiUl2N2JOSWXww
            situation: "Test2"
        -K6rPqbkBHJ-K8znVzay
            situation: "Test3"
```

I have inserted the data from an HTML page via a form like this...

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="situation">Add a situation</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="situation" placeholder="Situation" ng-model="situation">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="add_situation()"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin" ng-show="loading"></i> Add     </button>
</form>
```

The above form is calling the controller...

```
app.controller("situations", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
    $scope.add_situation = function () {
        var situation = $scope.situation;
        var ref = new Firebase("https://evalu8er.firebaseio.com/situations");

        ref.push().set({
            situation: situation
        });
    };
  }
]);
```

Now I want to get each of the situations back to the page, and this where it all goes wrong for me.

Inside the same controller as above I'm adding this....

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://evalu8er.firebaseio.com/user/situations/");
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
$scope.display_situatoins = snapshot.val(); 
}, function (errorObject) {
console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

And on the HTML page I have added

```
<li data-ng-repeat="x in display_situatoins">
    {{ x }}
</li>
```

When the page loads it DOES NOT show me the data until I enter something in the form field,

**Question 1/3)** 
How do I get the data to show on page load?

When it does load it looks like this...

```
{"situation":"Test"}
{"situation":"Test2"}
{"situation":"Test3"}
```

And what I want is just to show a list of the situations like this..

```
Test
Test2
Test3
```

**Question 2/3)** 
How do I just show the situation values as above?

And when I do add a new item it gets listed at the bottom, how do I order the list with the new items at the top?

**Question 3/3)** 
How do I order the list so the new items appear first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Use AngularFire for synchronized collections.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)**

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function MyCtrl($scope, rootRef, $firebaseArray) {
   $scope.situations = $firebaseArray(rootRef.child('situations');
}
```

Then in your template for `MyCtrl`, you can do an `ng-repeat` on the `situations` array.

```
<li ng-repeat="situation in situations">
    {{ situation.situation }}
</li>
```

The `{{ situation.situation }}` part looks awkward because of the naming. If you change the property `situation` to something like `text` or `title` it would look like:

```
<li ng-repeat="situation in situations">
    {{ situation.title }}
</li>
```